# Debugging end-to-end LAN problems

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

Working from home, often my internet connection isn't as fast or as robust as I would like it to be. However, I'm not sure what part of the network is letting me down - is it the connection coming into the house? Is it because I have multiple users all putting a strain on the network all at once? Is it just a lack of good WiFi signal?

The problem is, I don't know how to approach this in a principled way. Having tried a few different devices, it seems like going over ethernet offers a stable and fast connection (unsurprising), and sitting closer to the combo modem/router/WAP offers a faster, more stable connection (again, unsurprising). What seems to negatively impact the connection (mostly in terms of robustness, rather than speed) is having multiple users all connect at once.

Are there any open source tools available that I can use to try and get a better understanding of the network bottlenecks? My modem/router/WAP is ISP supplied, and whilst I have considered using it in modem-only mode, with a DD-WRT router attached to improve performance, I would like to be a bit more scientific and get some baseline measurements before going down this route. I've tried pinging the router over WiFi, and I get a RTT of anything from 3ms through 500ms, up to timing out:

```
--- 192.168.0.1 ping statistics ---
509 packets transmitted, 326 received, 35.9529% packet loss, time 511070ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 1.993/49.319/767.296/132.476 ms
```

I've also used iw to get my signal strength and it appears to be reasonably good (~-53dBm).

Any suggestions, tools or tips would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [I would like] to approach this in a principled way.

Hook up a computer by Ethernet directly to the modem temporarily and do a speed test. Eliminate this source as a problem (if it is not a problem).

> My modem/router/WAP is ISP supplied, and whilst I have considered
> using it in modem-only mode, with a DD-WRT router attached to improve
> performance,

I recommend this and do this myself with entry-level commercial routers.

> seems like going over ethernet offers a stable and fast connection
> (unsurprising), and sitting closer to the combo modem/router/WAP
> offers a faster, more stable connection

This is normal.

Now in your home layout, determine where wireless is best located. This may or may not be where the ISP put their modem.

If one wireless router strategically placed can service the house, then do that.

If necessary, look at two wireless routers or something like Ubiquiti Access Points to provide wireless where needed. I do this to service the second floor.

Determine how many users you have and what they are doing. Streaming movies all by wireless can overwhelm a wireless router. The value of an access point is that you can connect the access point by Ethernet and provide wireless at and near the location of the access point.

Your approach depends on your home layout and the number of wireless users. The above approach gives you a way to plan your network.

Comment: Sounds good! Are there are tools aside from doing speed tests I can use to measure before and after?

Comment: I use DU Meter (not expensive) to look at speed on my devices. That is handy to look for throughput.  For example I can run DU Meter on a wireless computer and see if there is steady throughput, dropout and so on. I have found that my second floor access point eliminates problems.